# Getting initializer-string for char array is too long. Is this a compiler error?

Tags: c++, c++17

```
static_assert(0<decltype(AType::Id)::MaxIdLen);
using __type = char[decltype(AType::Id):: MaxIdLen + 10000];
[[maybe_unused]] __type aa = ""; //error  initializer-string for char array is too long
```

I am getting this weird compiler error saying the initializer string is too long. But it is actually not. The first static_assert passed.

Has anyone seen such an issue before? I am using clang.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but please read [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier) Using leading double underscore in `__type` is not allowed.

Comment: Just how big is `MaxIdLen`? I need to use around `1000000000` to get that error

Comment: As for the error you get, first of all please try to create a proper [mre] to show us. Then copy-paste the *full* and *complete* error output you get, as text, info your question.

Answer (score 1):

> ... compiler error saying the initializer string is too long. But it is actually not.

The compiler is not telling you that the string is too long to init `aa`. It's telling you that it's more data than it can handle, presumably because `decltype(AType::Id)::MaxIdLen` is a large value.

The compiler doesn't just store the string literal in the character array. It initialises the entire character array by using the string literal as a prefix, and padding the rest with zeros.